# Can you use a FileInterceptor with a TransformPipe

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I've met an issue with the `TransformPipe` - it works as long, as I don't use the `FileInterceptor`. Since I need both functionalities it confused me. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1227) on Github, but Kamil wrote on it, that it is a normal framework behavior. Nor I, nor my friends, didn't find any references to this "normal" behavior in the official documentation. Do you have any ideas?

Code is [here](https://gist.github.com/hypeofpipe/08b612c1f1f3f366dfffeca1aba88766):

#### Controller

```
@UsePipes(SamplePipe)
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
@Post()
samplePost(@UploadedFile() file) {
  return file
}
```

#### Pipe

```
@Injectable()
export class SamplePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    console.log("I'm working")
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Pipes`](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) only work as the following types: `'body' | 'query' | 'param' | 'custom'` corresponding to `@Body()`, `@Query()`, `@Param()` or [custom decorators](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) like `@User()`. In your example you don't have any of these and that's why the pipe is not applied.

So if you add one of these to your example, the pipe will be applied (in this case to `@Body()`).

```
@UsePipes(SamplePipe)
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
@Post()
samplePost(@UploadedFile() file, @Body() body) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return file
}
```

If you use `@UsePipes()` the pipe will be applied everywhere where applicable. You can also use `@Body(SimplePipe) body` to only apply the pipe to the body.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the difference between controller-scope pipes and argument-scope ones.

Comment: I'm assuming your referring to my last paragraph? If you for example have multiple `@Param`s in your route, then `@UsePipes` is applied to all of them, whereas argument-scope ones only apply to one `@Param`. I don't see where there is a mistake, can you clarify?

Comment: Pipes are however never applied to the route itself but only its arguments. If you wanted to apply it to the whole route you'd use an Interceptor instead.

Comment: I've gave up on this framework, but the problem was in old ES target in tsconfig